# mostrar div si si existe dato dentro de array json en localstorage

Tags: angular

Buenas estoy creando unos favoritos almacenándolos en el localstorage
y tengo problemas a la hora de crear una condición para mostrar el botón de añadir a favoritos o no mostrarlo si ja existe el item en el local storage

Más o menos tengo por ejemplo el siguiente array:

```html
[{id: 33, user_id: 15, ...},
{id: 56, user_id: 15, ...},
{id: 32, user_id: 15, ...},
{id: 87, user_id: 15, ...},]
```

Entonces en el código estoy creando una condición de que me muestre un div solo si existen almacenados favoritos en el local storage y si hay alguno que coincide con el ID del item listado por ejemplo el 33 que es la variable (Car.id):

```html
<div *ngIf="storageFav && storageFav.indexOf(Car.id) >= 0">ya existe en favoritos</div>
```

la cuestión es que no funciona siempre me devuelve que no existe aunque si exista almacenado en el local storag.

*He hecho un console log y me esta recogiendo bien la variable y el array del local storage lo que falla es el indexOF que no esta buscando correctamente por id
EL proyecto esta en angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que `storageFav` es el array que mostrás al principio, con `indexOf`, estas intentando buscar un id en el array, pero este contiene objetos.

Deberías hacer algo así:

```
storageFav.some(function(fav) { return fav.id === Car.id })
```

[some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) va a devolver true al encontrar algún objeto en el array con el mismo valor que `Car.id`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero me da un error el codigo; Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

Comment: veo que es por culpa del =>

Comment: Es otra forma de escribir funciones, se puede reemplazar por function, voy a editar la respuesta

Comment: me sale otro error, compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' nose si comente que era para un ngIf de angular

Comment: HE probado i funciona perfecto incluso la primera opción que escribiste en un componente de angular pero en un *ngIf="" que es donde lo necesitaría falla

Comment: y si lo pasas a un controller y usas la variable en el view? Sería mucho más limpio que tener lógica directamente en el view.